# Javascript doesn't detect when file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here:

Javascript:

```
function chooseFile() {
  $("#imgInput").click();
}

$("#imgInput").change(function(){
  console.log('hi');
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="imgInput" name="imgInput" />
<input type="button" class="upload-btn" id="upload-init" onclick="chooseFile()" value="Choose image"></input>
```

When I click the button, chooseFile() works and the file selection comes up, I select the file and it uploads the "imgInput" element with the file name and such, but

```
$("#imgInput").change(function(){
  console.log('hi');
});
```

Is not being called at all, why is this? Yes I have JQuery included.

Comment: I don't know, i'm fairly new to javascript, how can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't work that way -> http://jsfiddle.net/ycx8Q/, and you don't close an input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ycx8Q/2/